# How do i return different Views based on conditions in the Action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

My Index action method returns a View that shows a list of QuestionViewModel objects. Each QuestionViewModel object has a Question_Type property:

```
public Question_Type Question_Type { get; set; }
```

When a user pushes the edit button, i would like to return different Views based on that Question Type. For instance, if a Question is of type "Multiple Choice", i would like to return a View that uses:

```
@model EditMCQQuestionViewModel
```

and if the question is of type "Matrix" i would like to return a View that uses

```
@model EditMatrixQuestionViewModel
```

is this possible through a single action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the view name

```
if (isMultiChoiceQuestion)
{    

    return View("MultiChoiceView", multiChoiceData);
}
if (isMatrixQuestion)
{    

    return View("MatrixView", matrixData);
}
```

you may beable to use the same view, just pass in different viewmodel.